# asp.net site content private (Not Searchable on internet)

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I've built a web portal on ASP.NET web forms. I have content/blogs on my page which I do not want to be searchable on the internet (I want to make it private only logged in user can view it).

Can anyone guide me how should I achieve it?

Comment: I get the content from Database and show it on the page upon request. What I mean is that my content is dynamic not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a robots.txt file, which will tell search engines to ignore certain folders or contents.
Example: robots.txt

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /PrivateContent/
Disallow: /AdminStatistics.html
```

This example tells all search engines to ignore the contents within the folder `/PrivateContent`, and the `AdminStatistics.html` page.

Of course, this will not block casual users (or hackers who intentionally search for robots.txt files).  For that, you are better off limiting access via your `web.config` file.
Example: web.config

```
<Configuration>
    <!-- This section block unauthenticated user access to the AdminStatistics.aspx page only. 
         It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
    <location path="AdminStatistics.aspx">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <deny users="?" />
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
    <!-- This section blocks unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are 
         stored in the PrivateContent folder.  -->
    <location path="PrivateContent">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

(code copied from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316871)